# nginx and ssl certificate

Tags: ssl, nginx, certificate, ssl-certificate

I would like to provide a ssl support of my site under Nginx.
First, I have tried to use self-signed certificate but As you know The browser complains that

> This Connection is Untrusted

Second, I tried to order a free certificate from well-known Certificate Authority (symantec.com). But it sends me a certificate in form:

> -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- MIIFhzCCBG+gAwIBAgIQIe7e9lh4GqB0cr9kdPKPbjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADCB
>   yzELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxFzAVBgNVBAoTDlZlcmlTaWduLCBJbmMuMTAwLgYDVQQL
>   EydGb3IgVGVzdCBQdXJwb3NlcyBPbmx5LiAgTm8gYXNzdXJhbmNlcy4xQjBABgNV
>   BAsTOVRlcm1zIG9mIHVzZSBhdCBodHRwczovL3d3dy52ZXJpc2lnbi5jb20vY3Bz
>   L3Rlc3RjYSAoYykwOTEtMCsGA1UEAxMkVmVyaVNpZ24gVHJpYWwgU2VjdXJlIFNl
>   cnZlciBDQSAtIEcyMB4XDTEzMDcwNTAwMDAwMFoXDTEzMDgwNDIzNTk1OVowgasx
>   CzAJBgNVBAYTAlVBMQ0wCwYDVQQIEwRLeWl2MQ0wCwYDVQQHFARLeWl2MQ0wCwYD
>   VQQKFARVSUlQMRgwFgYDVQQLFA9zeXN0ZW0gYW5hbHlzaXMxOjA4BgNVBAsUMVRl
>   cm1zIG9mIHVzZSBhdCB3d3cudmVyaXNpZ24uY29tL2Nwcy90ZXN0Y2EgKGMpMDUx
>   GTAXBgNVBAMUEGVmaWxpbmcudWlwdi5vcmcwggEiMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4IB
>   DwAwggEKAoIBAQDOq5JajVn8VEINqH6N61f8BwS3M2U9mIcwGt7Q829f+RaYqcF/
>   /+2+Zzmv72Hismgo6cu5N/ONtEBpJ69zkDjC9vD3IluCSimtu9CyMfG0z+V4tRr8
>   XxmdMnzSJNs+aBxM+ljODVuYjQ5r2YCsPl/GeVAHn41Qa76m0Efz1+XgfsmoSxSe
>   hhwBB7upJ1YvalRRvcGFGmqMQFiy2+8g/l3gCAuCgt+qniEoyNnOGWArkMm5pNUN
>   v0ciaDr8OTzBCx+RvI5sUA2+iM4mm7Jl7i9oKO6YvcXhpIBOHQDFuGkF5IEoyKAC
>   1ioBByqN9OT5UicTY25PddE133WU0gN1cBwXAgMBAAGjggGDMIIBfzAbBgNVHREE
>   FDASghBlZmlsaW5nLnVpcHYub3JnMAkGA1UdEwQCMAAwDgYDVR0PAQH/BAQDAgWg
>   MEMGA1UdHwQ8MDowOKA2oDSGMmh0dHA6Ly9TVlJUcmlhbC1HMi1jcmwudmVyaXNp
>   Z24uY29tL1NWUlRyaWFsRzIuY3JsMEoGA1UdIARDMEEwPwYKYIZIAYb4RQEHFTAx
>   MC8GCCsGAQUFBwIBFiNodHRwczovL3d3dy52ZXJpc2lnbi5jb20vY3BzL3Rlc3Rj
>   YTAdBgNVHSUEFjAUBggrBgEFBQcDAQYIKwYBBQUHAwIwHwYDVR0jBBgwFoAUKBcT
>   ir3WorXcBiy3to7aEGZgbuUwdAYIKwYBBQUHAQEEaDBmMCQGCCsGAQUFBzABhhho
>   dHRwOi8vb2NzcC52ZXJpc2lnbi5jb20wPgYIKwYBBQUHMAKGMmh0dHA6Ly9TVlJU
>   cmlhbC1HMi1haWEudmVyaXNpZ24uY29tL1NWUlRyaWFsRzIuY2VyMA0GCSqGSIb3
>   DQEBBQUAA4IBAQC4SQgLwIcrsvrdQlEpP3kQFJMtPBeoYPYouMfT/Fa4VtsL8Vxi
>   0YqGY8MGXPeESCqEFSciD8ZTaUvbMqaZe/iBPpsyLBpI2+aeksJBwMYtRLASCzIG
>   -----END CERTIFICATE-----

But Nginx needs to be a .key and .cer files.

**Any suggestions how to get form well-known CA a free certificate (.key and .cer file)?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the `.cer` file, the `.key` is the key you used to produce this `.cer` file, try to remember how you got this `.cer` file, you probably generated a key file on your device, then created a certificate signing request out of it `.csr` and then uploaded it to get this certificate correct ?

you should already have the key file.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Yes, first, I created a csr file. Second, I uploaded it to CA service. a csr file is my key file, isn't it?

Comment: yea but to create the csr you need a key, how did you create the csr

Comment: Thanks, Mohammed. First, I created a .key file. I forgot it.

Answer (score 1):

Wrote a tutorial about Let's Encrypt TSL/SSL certificates (free trusted ssl certificates for everybody!) on Apache or Nginx, including auto-renewal of your certificates. [Let`s Encrypt Guide](https://www.code-skate.com/lets-encrypt-free-ssl-for-your-website-or-blog/). It's super easy and works like charm!